# Issues getting my input value into an innerHTML - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot get the input value to go into my invitation on submit. After pressing submit the values are stored as I have checked the values in my array using

`document.getElementById("volunteersName" + index).value;`

all the values are storing properly.

however when I check the innerHTML using

`document.getElementById("name" + index).innerHTML;`

It still shows empty even though they should equal as I have set them to equal each other using

`document.getElementById("name" + index).innerHTML = document.getElementById("volunteersName" + index).value;`

Please help me see the light in what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

*** Partial code below ***

HTML

```
    <section id="pageForm">
        <form action="#">
            <label for="numberOfVolunteers">Number Of Volunteers:</label>
            <input id="numberOfVolunteers" type="number" onkeypress = "event()" name="numberOfVolunteers" placeholder="Enter Number Of Volunteers" />
            <p id="newFields"></p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input class="visibility" onclick="invite()" type="button" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </section>

    <div id="test">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

JS

```
function invite() {
    var volunteersName = [];
    var name = [];
    for (index = 1; index < volunteersName.length; index++) {
            document.getElementById("name" + index).innerHTML = document.getElementById("volunteersName" + index).value;

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider trimming that massive amount of code down to just the *pertinent* code to the problem. This makes it much easier for us to help you and less to wade through to understand your problem. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your CSS, for example, is irrelevant for this question.

Comment: Sorry I'll narrow it down a bit. I'm new to JavaScript so not exactly sure what someone will need.

Comment: OK so you've got a couple of issues. Firstly, you're calling `event()` from your HTML but I can't see where that's defined, so that'll be generating console errors. Always check the error console. Secondly, your template literal is malformed. That syntax isn't how you intersperse dynamic elements among the static content. For that you need `${somethingdynamichere}` syntax, so in your case `inviteForm.innerHTML = `Hello <span id=name${index}> Volunteers...`

Comment: The event() was for something separate and works great that was on the top portion and was only for the enter key not the submit button. I edited the code down a bit more and is only an issue now with the invite(). I need those values to equal each other using only JavaScript(no jquery allowed). I'm taking those values and inputting them into a onscreen readout that was created by the event().

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues here:

- The code inside the loop in `invite()` will never execute because `index` (1) will always be more than the length of `volunteersName` (0)
- The syntax for creating the span where the name will go is wrong. If you want to use string interpolation, you need to use `... id="name${index}" ...` inside the backticks

For the first problem I suggest you use the input value from the first input to set the closing condition for the for loop:

```
var numberOfVolunteers = document.getElementById("numberOfVolunteers").value;
for (index = 1; index <= numberOfVolunteers; index++) {
```

For the second, your code should look something like the following:

```
inviteForm.innerHTML = `Hello <span id="name${index}"> Volunteers Name </span>!
<br/>
<br/> You have been invited to volunteer for an event held by <span id='organizationName2'>Organizations Name</span> on <span id='eventDate2'>Event Date</span>. Please come to the following website: <span id='websiteURL2'>Website URL</span> to sign up as a volunteer.
<br/>
<br/> Thanks!
<br/>
<br/>
<span id='hostName2'>Hosts Name</span>`;
```

Comment: Actually I'm a bit confused. For the first problem you were saying for the length of `volunteersName` but in the suggested soultion you are showing for `numberOfVolunteers` did you mean to put `volunteersName` in the suggestion?

Comment: No, the `volunteersName` array you have is redundant, unless you actually need to put the names inside, which you can do inside the loop. The problem is that when you start the loop, the array is empty so its length will always be less than the initial index of 1. `numberofVolunteers` is a new variable that holds the value of the corresponding input in the first view. You can call it whatever but you need that value to determine how many iterations to do.

Comment: For the first section I already have this code which I think is pretty much what you are telling me to add except I put it in a while loop instead of a for loop. ```var numberOfVolunteers = document.getElementById("numberOfVolunteers").value;
        var index = 1;
        var volunteersName = ["volunteersName"];
  while (numberOfVolunteers >= 1)```

Comment: I also have this code at the bottom of the while loop ```index++;
  numberOfVolunteers--;```

Comment: Yes, you can use a while loop, but that while loop looks pretty dodgy (unless you are decrementing the value of `numberOfVolunteers` at the end of each iteration). Did my suggestion not work for you?

Comment: Okay. What's the problem?

Comment: The while loop works great and preforms exactly how I need it too. The problem is I need the value that is storing when I press submit to go into the innerHTML readout I created. I cannot get the stored volunteersName = name

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the elements using developer tools to see if it's there? You have that section hidden. Are you showing it through JS when the submit is clicked?

Comment: When I inspect the element yes it is showing as there. The layout is as follows. The user enters number of volunteers in input and presses enter. The enter key hides the number of volunteers input, unhides the rest of the form, unhides a submit button while adding the number entered as text boxes for the user to input names whatever number that might be. It also creates the readout for every person and hides it but leaving blanks in the form so when they press submit it will take to inputs and place them into the readout while unhiding it at the same time.

Comment: Actually I turned off the hiding for now so I could get this to work and I will hide and unhide it after I get the function working properly first. I know how to hide and unhide no problem

Comment: I found my issue. I just needed to pull the variable out of the function and make it global. Thanks for your responses